# What do parenthesis without quantifiers in Lexer rules?

Tags: antlr4

Assume the following grammer:

```
grammar Demo; 

start: START_BLOCK SEPERATOR;

START_BLOCK: '-.-.-';

ID: ( LETTER SEPERATOR ) (LETTER SEPERATOR)+;
fragment LETTER: L_A|L_K;
fragment L_A: '.-';
fragment L_K: '-.-';

SEPERATOR: '!';
```

I pass the following input to the grammar: `-.-.-!`

I'd expect that ANTLR recognizes the tokens START_BLOCK and SEPERATOR. But instead it finds a single Token of type `ID`.

I figured that I can fix the problem by removing the first couple of parenthesis in lexer rule "ID":

```
ID: LETTER SEPERATOR (LETTER SEPERATOR)+;
```

Now everything works fine, but why? What did the parenthesis above do to my grammar?

Comment: Looks to be a bug to me: `ID: (LETTER SEPERATOR) (LETTER SEPERATOR)+;` and `ID: LETTER SEPERATOR (LETTER SEPERATOR)+;` should produce the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ANTLR 4 which is fixed for the 4.0.1 release. See: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/224